# Why are 2 files different even after merging the 2 branches on git?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

At work, we are creating branches from the **dev** branch. So I created **feature1** branch from dev.
I modified a function on **file1**.

And then I pulled from remote **dev**, and then merged **dev** into **feature1**, in the meantime **dev** has changed.

The problem is that even after merging, the **file1** doesn't contain the changes from **dev**.

So if I'm pushing my changes, **file1** will not be up to date.

I was expecting git to add the changes in all the functions in **feature1**, and tell me there is a conflict in my functions that should be resolved manually.

Why isn't there a conflict?

Comment: Have you merged the remote `dev` into `feature1`, or your local `dev` without the remote changes?

Comment: Can you post `git log --graph --decorate` which shows `dev`, `feature1`, and the merge?

Comment: `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` that is.

Comment: @choroba I pulled the dev branch from remote branch, and then merged of course

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for several  reasons, one of them could be that you have not update your dev branch. First go to **dev** branch with "git checkout dev" command, once you are there write the following commands:

```
git fetch
git status (To see that you are actually tracking the origin/dev branch)
git pull (To update your dev branch)
```

Then go to your **feature1** branch with "git checkout feature1" and do,

```
git merge dev
```

Another thing you can do is check the dev branch with "git log", the last commit should be the change you are looking for.

Comment: This is what I did, I pulled dev, and then merged dev into feature1, of course.
this is why I don't understand.